# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first in vb 2010 professional

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb 2010 professional and i have "There is already an open `DataReader` associated with this `Connection` which must be closed first" problem

This is my full source code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick


    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader


    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim query As String
    Dim spath As String
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim mysound As Media.SoundPlayer


    query = "select* from penjara.info"
    Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

    While Reader.Read
        count = count + 1

        query = "Select penjara.info where  no =count"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

        If (Reader.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (Reader.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
            Form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            mysound.PlayLooping()
        ElseIf (Reader.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (Reader.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
            Form3.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            mysound.PlayLooping()
        ElseIf (Reader.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (Reader.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
            Form4.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            mysound.PlayLooping()
        ElseIf (Reader.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (Reader.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
            Form5.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            mysound.PlayLooping()
        ElseIf (Reader.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (Reader.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
            Form5.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            mysound.PlayLooping()
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is showing because the connection is already open when trying to execute the code in  in next tick of timer. so it can be avoided by open connection through this code

```
  If MysqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    MysqlConn.Close()
  else
    MysqlConn.Open()
  End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looping on the Reader then trying to open a new Reader on it

```
While Reader.Read              <<< looping on this
    count = count + 1

    query = "Select penjara.info where  no =count"
    Command =  New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)      <<<<<<<<<<<<< trying to open new one

    Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader                    <<<<<<<<<<<<< trying to open new one
```

You should be creating new connections and readers (not reusing the variables) in the loop. They should be replaced like so:

```
While Reader.Read              <<< looping on this
    count = count + 1

    Using con as New MySqlConnection(MysqlConn.ConnectionString)
    Using cmd as New MySqlCommand(query, con)  
    Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

and your IF statements should be using rdr:

```
If (rdr.GetInt32("keadaan") .... etc
```

and at the bottom on the loop

```
End Using
End Using
End Using
```

As this will close down the open connections.

Also the query looks suspect are you sure you didn't want something like...

```
query = String.Format("Select penjara.info where  no ={0}", count)
```

Comment: i change it but the problem still same . i change the command and reader but still not working.. help me :(

Comment: You say you've changed it. What change did you make? I've edited the answer. Please review the whole thing

Comment: please edit you question. Don't post code in comments.